# What HTML can I use with SweetAlert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sweetalert

I'm trying to find the allowable HTML that I can use with the SweetAlert alert function (http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

I found that I can use headings (h1 etc.) and  for example, but if I try to add inline styles such as style="color:blue;" then the alert no longer works.  The different heading styles don't seem to make any difference.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<script>
swal({   
title: "text<br /><br />text",   
text: "<strong>text</strong>",   
timer: 4000, html: true,  
showConfirmButton: false });
</script>
```

If I want to make the alert match the style of my site, then I guess I need to modify the SweetAlert CSS.

Please help me to work out what HTML is available to use within SweetAlert without breaking the alert function.

Comment: If you found the feedback useful, please mark the answer as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look's like you just need to set the `html` option to `true` when you initialize the plugin. That will prevent SweetAlert from escaping HTML. It should allow you to use any element.

Beware that this could allow XSS attacks, but that only applies if your alert content is user generated.

From the docs:

```
swal({
    title: "HTML <small>Title</small>!",
    text: "A custom <span style='color: #F8BB86'>html<span> message.",
    html: true
});
```

Comment: Sorry to clarify - I have set the html option to  html: true,

Comment: I noticed that, and I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2017.**

The solution html = true came from version SweetAlert 1.x.
This is no longer supported in actual version.
Now you put the html content in the "html" option and leave the "text" option off.

Works fine in '6.9.1':

```
swal({
        title: 'Title',
        html: 'A custom <span style="color: #F8BB86">html<span> message.'
});
```

[Javascript Sweet Alert and html link inside text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030856/javascript-sweet-alert-and-html-link-inside-text/49230935#49230935)