# Javascript Sweet Alert and html link inside text

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

i have the following SweetAlert Code..

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('.patient-details').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
        var gender = $(this).attr('data-gender');
        var age = $(this).attr('data-age');
        var country = $(this).attr('data-country');
        var state = $(this).attr('data-state');
        var address = $(this).attr('data-address');
        var report = $(this).attr('data-report');
        swal({
            title: name,
            text: "Gender: " + gender +"\n" + "Age: " + age +"\n" + "Country: " + country +"\n" + "State: " + state +"\n" + "Address: " + address +"\n" + "Report: " + report,
            confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4",
            imageUrl: "images/avatar/user.png",
        });
    });
</script>
```

The var report is a link and i need the link displayed in the modal. I tried html: true etc. html is no longer used. Instead use the content object. as doc says:

https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#content

https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

But i as a newbie is unable to make sense out of it.

Requesting help on how to display the link in the modal and the link to be opened in new window.

**Update:**
Since the solutions provided were not working i used another approach using html to resolve it. Need to remove text, else text will be default. Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/pamela123/pen/GOJZgo

Comment: If you can provide any jsfiddle or codepen link to workout then it should more helpful to identify the exact issue.

Answer (score 5):

Found this answer [here](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/845), all credits to
[Tristan Edwards](https://github.com/t4t5)

```js
const el = document.createElement('div')
el.innerHTML = "Here's a <a href='http://google.com'>link</a>"

swal({
  title: "Hello!",
  content: el,
})
```

Answer (score 3):

As the doc says, `html` is deprecated and no longer works.

They have replaced `html` with `content`, which is not a string any longer, but an Object.

This `content` object looks like this :

```
content: {
    element: "input",
    attributes: {
      placeholder: "Type your password",
      type: "password",
    }
  }
```

So I guess you can build your own link like this :

```
content: {
    element: "a",
    attributes: {
      href : report
    }
  }
```

...and then simply pass the `content` object to `swal` :

```
swal({
 content: {
        element: "a",
        attributes: {
          href : report
        }
 }
})
```

Note that this is untested, I'm not sure if `element:"a"` works. But anyway, the doc gives a better way :

```
var slider = document.createElement("input");
slider.type = "range";

swal({
  content: slider
});
```

So you can create a link this way :

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href= report;

swal({
  content: link
});
```

As an aside, you can heavily optimize the code you provided in your question by caching `$(this)` (which is expensive to create) and reuse it. Also, `.attr("data-x")` has a shorthand, `.data("x")`.

```
var $this = $(this)
var name = $this.data('name');
var gender = $this.data('gender');
var age = $this.data('age');
var country = $this.data('country');
var state = $this.data('state');
var address = $this.data('address');
var report = $this.data('report');
```

OR even better :

```
var attributes = $(this).data()
```

which gives an object containing all your data attributes. Which you can then reach using :

```
text: "Gender: " + attributes['gender'] +"\n" + "Age: " + attributes['age'] +"\n" + "Country: " + attributes['country'] +"\n" + "State: " + attributes['state'] +"\n" + "Address: " + attributes['address'] +"\n" + "Report: " + attributes['report']
```

Or in ES6 :)

```
text: `Gender: ${attributes['gender']}\n
        Age: ${attributes['age']}\n
        Country: ${attributes['country']}\n
        State: ${attributes['state']}\n
        Address: ${attributes['address']}\n
        Report: ${attributes['report']}`
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. 
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href= report;

swal({
  content: link
});

Thank you for the wonderful suggestions.

Comment: It must work. It's exactly what's written in the doc.

Comment: @ Jeremy Thille Here is the code Pen..the original one
https://codepen.io/pamela123/pen/GOJZgo

Comment: Well, it's not working because you have a syntax error line 18. Check your code. Codepen tells you it has an error.

Comment: If you fix the simple syntax errors (double quotes instead of simple quotes) it works... Here : https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/wPazMw

Comment: No..I was testing it and hence error. The solutions provided were not working. I tried other solution using html:
https://codepen.io/pamela123/pen/GOJZgo

Thanks for the help anyway. Especially your details about using $(this).

Comment: The codepen link I gave you is working... You have the full working solution. If you're happy with that, maybe I deserve an upvote and you accept my answer :) So I get some rep

Comment: Please note that I have already an alternative solution and the link you provided was my own codepen testing. So the solutions provided were not answer and it was not working. But you helped me quite a lot with other discussions. The  content: link still does not work. But i will upvote you for other discussions.

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Both your Codepen link and mine are working perfectly. Unless, of course, you use IE or Safari...

Answer (score 2):

> As Jeremy Thille found out in his commentary on Oct. 31 '17 at 10:36:

You do not need to use the option "content" for a simple link in the text.
The option "text" can only display pure text, no html.
However, the option "html" can display html.

Not to be confused with the old version SweetAlert 1.X: There you had to set html = true.

In SeewtAlert2, the html is set directly in the "html" option. Do not use option "text" in this case.

Works fine in sweetAlert.version = '6.9.1';

Example of Jeremy Thille:

```
$('.patient-details').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this)
  var name = $this.data('name');
  var gender = $this.data('gender');
  var age = $this.data('age');
  var country = $this.data('country');
  var address = $this.data('address');
  var report = $this.data('report');

  swal({
  title: name,
  html:
      "Gender: " + gender +"<br>" +
     "Age: " + age +"<br>" +
     "Country: " + country +"<br>" +
     "Address: " + address +"<br>" +
     "Report: " + report +"<br>" +
      "<a href='report'>Report</a> " +
     "and other HTML tags"
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/wPazMw

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the following (I have never used sweet alert, but after reading the documentation this is what I would try)

```
var link= document.createElement("a");
link.href =  report  // or link.setAttribute("href", report)


swal({
title: name,
text: "Gender: " + gender +"\n" + "Age: " + age +"\n" + "Country: " + country +"\n" + "State: " + state +"\n" + "Address: " + address +"\n" + "Report: " + report,
confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4",
imageUrl: "images/avatar/user.png",
content:link
});
});
```

**Or**

```
swal({
    title: name,
    text: "Gender: " + gender +"\n" + "Age: " + age +"\n" + "Country: " + country +"\n" + "State: " + state +"\n" + "Address: " + address +"\n" + "Report: " + report,
    confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4",
    imageUrl: "images/avatar/user.png",
    content:{
      element:"a",
      attributes:{
        href:report
      }
     }
    });
    });
```

**hope that helps**

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. 
content:{
      element:"a",
      attributes:{
        href:report
      }
     }

Comment: what about the first ?

Comment: did you also try the link.setAttribute("href", report) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not still able to find a solution, I tried recreating the modal 
https://codepen.io/AJALACOMFORT/pen/zPGqNe?editors=0010

```
window.onload= function(){
  var that = $(".patient-details")
  var name = $(that).attr('data-name');
var gender = $(that).attr('data-gender');
var age = $(that).attr('data-age');
var country = $(that).attr('data-country');
var address = $(that).attr('data-address');
var report = $(that).attr('data-report');

   //creates h2
    var h2 = document.createElement("h2")
        //adds text
        h2.innerHTML = name
  //creates p tag 
    var p = document.createElement("p")
         p.innerHTML =  "Gender: " + gender +"\n" + "Age: " + age +"\n" + "Country: " + country +"\n"  + "Address: " + address +"\n" + "Report: " + report
  //creates button
  var button = document.createElement("button")
    //adds the onclick function
      button.setAttribute("onclick", "callbutton(event)")
  button.innerHTML ="ok"
  button.className += "confirm"
  var link = document.createElement("a")
      link.setAttribute("href", report)
      link.innerHTML ="Link"
      link.className += "report-link"
  //appends all the elements into the mymodal div
  var modal = document.getElementById("modal-inner")
        modal.appendChild(h2)
          modal.appendChild(p)
          modal.appendChild(link)
        modal.appendChild(button)


}
 //listens to click event of the checkbox
  function callbutton(){
      document.getElementById("checkboxabove").checked = false;
  }
```

Hopefully it helps. (Note I did not use the same transition effect like in sweet alert, so adjust as you please)