# How to add more html to sweetalert after html to content update?

Tags: sweetalert2

I saw previously you could edit the html portion of the sweetalert, but now that has been changed to content instead of doing raw html. Is there a way to go back to using html or another way of adding in an input. I saw in another post that it may be better to just use a modal instead.

https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/451 here is the guide with the html.

Comment: Make sure you're not mixing SweetAlert and SweetAlert2 - those are two different projects, SweetAlert repo: https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert SweetAlert2 repo: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SweetAlert2.

The plain HTML option still exists.
This is used as follows:

```
swal({
    title: 'Title',
    html: 'A custom <span style="color: #F8BB86">html<span> message.'
});
```

[Javascript Sweet Alert and html link inside text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030856/javascript-sweet-alert-and-html-link-inside-text/49230935#49230935)